# How can i tune my Jersey deployment on embedded Grizzly instance in terms of threading policy and parameters

Tags: jersey, grizzly

How can i set up parameters for thread-pool implementations?
What are the possible configuration options, and how can i find relevant documentation to start fine-tuning my application?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking into core grizzly configurations? 
http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/core-config.html

Comment: yes that was exactly where i started, what i am interested is how the Jersey request lifecycle uses threadpools and how to fine tune the behavior. And also the 'GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer' encapsulates and hides Grizzly specifics, which is a bit weird. I am on my way to read the source and design my own GrizzlyServerFactory version with some extra flavor of tuning...